# Слишком широкий TableLayout

Tags: android

Есть `GridLayout`, в котором находятся два `TableLayout`. Мне нужно, чтобы эти `TableLayout`'ы растягивались, согласно весам. Но почему-то первая разметка получается слишком широкой (хотя в приведённом коде две разметки должны занимать одинаковое пространство). Код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowCount="1">
    <TableLayout
        grid:layout_row="0"
        grid:layout_column="0"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:text="1" />
            <Button android:text="2" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        grid:layout_row="0"
        grid:layout_column="1"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:text="3" />
            <Button android:text="4" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Результат:

[image: слишком широко]

Почему так получается и как это исправить?

**Дополнение**

В реальном коде внутри `GridLayout` может быть несколько `TableLayout` и других представлений.

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть всё это в `LinearLayout` и указать в нём горизонтальную ориентацию, выставить веса для `TableLayout` 1 и 1 соответственно.

Comment: @Asgard в смысле вместо `GridLayout` `LinearLayout`? Это мне не очень подходит, ведь в реальном коде в `GridLayout` ещё много элементов, тех же табличных разметок.

Comment: Это обман зрения :)

Comment: @Imieee нет, обернуть - значит сделать родителем для `GridLayout`